# What SQL statement will determine which values in a set are not in a specified column?

Tags: sql, set

What SQL statement will determine which values in a set of values are NOT in a specified column?  Eg:

```
{"String1","String2","String3"}
```

What SQL statement will determine which of these string values are NOT in `Column1` of `Table1`?

No Linq as I am using VS2005.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know which of the strings in your list that do not exist as values in the table, or do you want the rows that have a value that's not in your list of values?

Comment: Is your question really about C#?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I want the values in the set that are NOT in `Column1`.

Comment: @MichaelBuen: correct, I have removed [C#]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 select *
 from 
 (
      select 'String1' as s 
      union select 'String2' 
      union select 'String3'
 ) as x
 where x.s not in (select column1 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE Table1.Column1 NOT IN ("String1", "String2", "String3")
```

Comment: Won't that give me ALL of `Column1` that is not in that set?

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator

eg.

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 IN ('String1','String2','String3')
```

Comment: That will give the values that ARE in `Column1`.  I want the values that are NOT in `Column1`.

Comment: Now it will give all the values in `Column1` that are not in the set.  I want the values in the set that are NOT in `Column1`.

Comment: Ive updated my answer is it ok now? perhaps you can provide more information about your question post a sample data and your desired result.

Comment: No, now it is telling me which values in `Column1` are in the set. I want to know which values in the set are NOT in `Column1`.

Comment: Then refer to the answer of Michael Buen ...that code should work

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```
select * from 
(
  select 'String1' as s 
  union select 'String2' 
  union select 'String3'
) as a
where not exists (select 'x' from Table1 where Column1 = a.s)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Column1 NOT IN 
(
'String1',
'String2',
'String3'
)
```